# Position problem in Custom list adapter after notifydatasetchange?

Tags: android, listview

friends,

i am using following custom adapter for android listview
problem i am facing is wrong position after calling notifydatasetchanged();

first time when i bind data with list position works perfect but after when i call notifydatasetchanged();
i get position parameter wrong

please guide what mistake am i doing any help would be appreciated.

```
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context,List<DalCategories> value) {

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            obj = value;


        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
             final  ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;


            if(convertView == null)
            {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_category_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.TextTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
            holder.checkBoxes = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkSubCategory);




              convertView.setTag(holder);

              }else
              {
                  holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

              }


    // while setting checkbox state after notify datasetchanged i get wrong position        

            if(obj.get(position).isIs_Selected())       
            {
                holder.checkBoxes.setChecked(true);

            }


            holder.checkBoxes
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(
                        CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {



                    if(obj.get(position).isIs_Any() && isChecked)
                    {

                            if( adapter != null)
                            {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }


                    }






                }
            });




            holder.TextTitle.setText(obj.get(position).getTitle());



            return convertView;
        }
 class ViewHolder 
     {
        public TextView TextTitle;
        public CheckBox checkBoxes;
     }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return obj.get(position);
    }

    }
```

Comment: one more interesting thing when i remove check if(convertView == null){}else{} then it works perfect :( but that is the efficient way which is causing me problem of position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling with integrating this adapter too, but I noticed the static keyword is missing from your holder class. Each time you call holder, it may not be what you think.

Take a look at this example. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html